# Linq Grouping/Parsing very slow

Tags: .net, performance, linq

I am making a call to 3rd party API to get around 58,000 rows in a list named **filteredList**. Class **T** contains a property that is duplicated throughout the list. So my requirements need me to first group the list items based on duplicate values (there could be potentially 20000 duplicates) using:

```
Dim duplicateEntries = filteredList.GroupBy(Function(x) x.CustomMemberId)
```

And once I know the list of duplicates, I have to append a suffix (a number after each value within the set using the following code snippet so there are no duplicates for the CustomMemberId property. For example, 1 set of duplicate values may have 34992078 as CustomMemberId. My requirement is to have the first CustomMemberId as 34992078 and each subsequent record with same member id will have it set to (after running the following code):

```
Old CustomMemberId    New CustomMemberId
34992078              349920781
34992078              349920782
34992078              349920783
34992078              349920784
34992078              349920785

For Each item As Object In duplicateEntries
        Dim num As Integer = 0

        Dim tempClubs As IOrderedEnumerable(Of ClubInformation) = filteredList.Where(Function(x) x.CustomMemberId = item.Key).OrderBy(Function(x) Convert.ToDateTime(x.createTimestamp))

        For Each club As ClubInformation In tempClubs
            club.CustomMemberId = If(num > 0, club.CustomMemberId + num.ToString(), club.CustomMemberId)
            num += 1
        Next
    Next
```

The logic seems to work just fine with a glitch that it takes about 2 hours to run the entire logic which is totally unacceptable. I can't change the logic to anything else (it has to be appending a number after each duplicate entry in a set, so please don't advise on changing it), so I would need help in making the query faster. Any pointers will be much appreciated.

**UPDATE** - Code added (after getting data from API) for better understanding

```
#Region "Remove ineligible types"

    LogAuditEntry("Starting removal of Ineligible types")

    Dim types = GetIneligibleMembershipTypes(_clientId)
    Dim typeList As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)

    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(types) Then
        typeList = types.Split(","c).ToList()
    End If
    fetched = 0
    totalFetched = 0
    Dim filteredList As New List(Of ClubInformation)()

    Do
        Dim count = list.Skip(totalFetched).Take(1000).Count
        Dim filtered = (From item In list.Skip(totalFetched).Take(1000)
                        Where Not typeList.Any(Function(x) item.MembershipType.Equals(x))     'dont consider ineligible membership types)
                        Select New ClubInformation() With {
                            .MemberId = item.MemberId,
                            .ReferringMemberId = item.ReferringMemberId,
                            .AgreementNumber = item.AgreementNumber,
                            .BeginDate = item.BeginDate,
                            .MembershipType = item.MembershipType,
                            .CustomMemberId = item.CustomMemberId,
                            .FirstName = item.FirstName,
                            .LastName = item.LastName,
                            .AddressLine1 = item.AddressLine1,
                            .AddressLine2 = item.AddressLine2,
                            .City = item.City,
                            .State = item.State,
                            .Zip = item.Zip,
                            .Country = item.Country,
                            .Email = item.Email,
                            .Telephone = item.Telephone,
                            .DateofBirth = item.DateofBirth,
                            .Status = item.Status,
                            .memberStatus = item.memberStatus,
                            .agreementEntrySource = item.agreementEntrySource,
                            .lastModifiedTimestamp = item.lastModifiedTimestamp,
                            .nextBillingDate = item.nextBillingDate,
                            .signDate = item.signDate,
                            .firstPaymentDate = item.firstPaymentDate,
                            .sinceDate = item.sinceDate,
                            .agreementEntrySourceReportName = item.agreementEntrySourceReportName,
                            .queueTimestamp = item.queueTimestamp,
                            .agreementPaymentMethod = item.agreementPaymentMethod,
                            .barcode = item.barcode,
                            .createTimestamp = item.createTimestamp,
                            .currentQueue = item.currentQueue,
                            .downPayment = item.downPayment,
                            .emergencyContactName = item.emergencyContactName,
                            .emergencyExt = item.emergencyExt,
                            .emergencyPhone = item.emergencyPhone,
                            .firstCheckInTimestamp = item.firstCheckInTimestamp,
                            .gender = item.gender,
                            .hasPhoto = item.hasPhoto,
                            .homeClub = item.homeClub,
                            .isActive = item.isActive,
                            .isConvertedProspect = item.isConvertedProspect,
                            .isNonMember = item.isNonMember,
                            .isPastDue = item.isPastDue,
                            .isPrimaryMember = item.isPrimaryMember,
                            .joinStatus = item.joinStatus,
                            .lastCheckInTimestamp = item.lastCheckInTimestamp,
                            .lateFeeAmount = item.lateFeeAmount,
                            .managedType = item.managedType,
                            .memberStatusDate = item.memberStatusDate,
                            .memberStatusReason = item.memberStatusReason,
                            .nextDueAmount = item.nextDueAmount,
                            .pastDueBalance = item.pastDueBalance,
                            .paymentFrequency = item.paymentFrequency,
                            .paymentPlan = item.paymentPlan,
                            .renewalType = item.renewalType,
                            .salesPersonHomeClub = item.salesPersonHomeClub,
                            .salesPersonId = item.salesPersonId,
                            .salesPersonName = item.salesPersonName,
                            .serviceFeeAmount = item.serviceFeeAmount,
                            .term = item.term,
                            .totalCheckInCount = item.totalCheckInCount,
                            .totalPastDueBalance = item.totalPastDueBalance,
                            .workPhonExt = item.workPhonExt
                        }).ToList()
        'Add to list
        filteredList.AddRange(filtered)
        fetched = count
        totalFetched += fetched
    Loop While fetched > 0

#End Region

    LogAuditEntry("Removed Ineligible types")

#Region "Appends number after duplicate club id + agreement no"

    Dim duplicateEntries = filteredList.GroupBy(Function(x) x.CustomMemberId)

    For Each item As Object In duplicateEntries
        Dim num As Integer = 0

        Dim tempClubs As IOrderedEnumerable(Of ClubInformation) = filteredList.Where(Function(x) x.CustomMemberId = item.Key).OrderBy(Function(x) Convert.ToDateTime(x.createTimestamp))

        For Each club As ClubInformation In tempClubs
            club.CustomMemberId = If(num > 0, club.CustomMemberId + num.ToString(), club.CustomMemberId)
            num += 1
        Next
    Next

    LogAuditEntry("Removed duplicates and added custom member id")

#End Region
```

**UPDATE 2** - Timelines

## =======================================================================

Time:26-Apr-16 3:33:22 AM

## Details:Removed Ineligible types

=======================================================================
Time:26-Apr-16 5:37:20 AM

## Details:Removed duplicates and added custom member id

======================================================================

Comment: The first thing you need to do is set `Option Strict On` in your code. That will help get rid of a lot of run-time errors by making sure they surface at compile time.

Comment: As I said, the code runs fine everytime without any errors. My key concern is the slowness with which the query executes. As you can see from timelines, it takes about 2 hours to remove duplicates.

Comment: What's the type of `list`?

Comment: Its a list of ClubInformation class which has about 50 fields. You can see Update  code for more details.

Comment: The code doesn't show the type of `list`. Is it just `List<ClubInformation>`? If not, what is it? How is it populated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's so slow because you are using [late binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0tcf61s1.aspx). Don't. With early binding your query will execute orders of magnitude faster.

Change

```
For Each item As Object In duplicateEntries
```

to

```
For Each item In duplicateEntries
```

to fix your problem.